# Flutter Tooltip on all widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to set a `tooltip` on a `Text` widget:

```
new Text(
    "Some content",
    tooltip: "Displays a message to you"
  )
```

This does not work. However it does work, as [mentioned here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html), on things like the `FloatingActionButton`:

```
new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: action,
    tooltip: "Action",
    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
  )
```

I understand that the `Text` class does simply not have `tooltip` implemented. I want to know if there is a way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can wrap your text into a [`Tooltip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html) widget.

```dart
Tooltip(message: "Hello World", child: new Text("foo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Tooltip(message: "This is the tooltip message", child: new Text("Show tooltip"));`

You can also provide a height, decoration and other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do that.
Wrap your Text Widget inside a flutter Tooltip Widget as mentioned above But it is triggered on the long press by default if you want it be triggered on a single tap You can its triggerMode property.