# Show hint text if user is trying to click on disabled Radio button

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to implement this feature:

> When user click on disabled radio buttons, it should display a hint text to tell user that it is not allowed to change choices.

I've checked [Tooltip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html), it is said:

> Wrap the button in a Tooltip widget to show a label when the widget long pressed (or when the user takes some other appropriate action).

Regarding to Tooltip, I only know how to implement it when user **long pressed** the widget to show tooltip.
I don't know how to achieve *when the user takes some other appropriate action* mentioned in above.

In my case, the appropriate action to trigger tooltip is **one click** on the disabled Radio button.

Other things I've tried:

- [Flutter Tooltip on all widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024222/flutter-tooltip-on-all-widgets)
- [Flutter how to update hint text
  with current value in TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348044/flutter-how-to-update-hint-text-with-current-value-in-textfield)

Still can't figure out.

**More Information:**

It doesn't have to be Tooltip, please advise any appropriate solution.
I am new to Flutter/Dart, I hope I have explained the issue clearly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can show `Tooltip` whenever user Taps on RadioButton in following way.

Following is the code for your reference: [***Run on DartPad***](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6b6ee33f01272dffc24419a811c10ecf)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  GlobalKey _toolTipKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              final dynamic tooltip = _toolTipKey.currentState;
              tooltip.ensureTooltipVisible();
            },
            child: Tooltip(
              key: _toolTipKey,
              message: 'button is disabled',
              child: Radio(
                groupValue: null,
                onChanged: null,
                value: null,
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Let me see, it's using GestureDetector && GlobalKey && Ontap. I will give a try and update later.

Comment: If this works for you don't forget to accept and up-vote the answer... :)

Comment: Absolutely! And it is good news that it works in my code! Thank you Kalpesh!

Comment: This solution also works with a disabled button. Thanks.